Can a priority be added to a question?
I've just asked this question about renaming a program.
When I wrote that question, I had seen that I could not compile my program, so that looked like an urgent question.
My task, however, is a client/server application and the server-side is far more urgent. And while waiting for the solution to my compilation error, I've found a way to populate my database and as the server-side is working now, which greatly reduce how urgent the compilation question it is for me.
I have mentioned this in the comments, but I believe there's no "priority" feature.
Wouldn't that be a good idea to cover issues like mine? Like this, Stack Overflow resources might be freed for other, more urgent matters.

Are you just looking for bounties?

@WeijunZhou: good idea, but bounties increase the priority of a question, while I'm looking for a way to decrease it.

Do you mean we should assign a subjective importance, priority, problem degree or problem size for an OP's question?

I don't get the reasoning. There isn't a horde of people working on every single question that gets posted. So, "decreasing the priority" is a meaningless thing to do. Chances are that if nobody answered within about 24 hours, then they won't answer on the 25th. Or anywhere soon. Questions tend to be answered either almost immediately, or later. There isn't a priority queue that they go through.

@Gimby: where do you get the right for writing such a thing? I am a member of this website for about nine years, and in that time, I have always treated this website the same way, as it is described in the help of the site. Whether or not other people like it or not should never be an argument! In top of that, I have also written quite some answers, hereby helping other members of this site. In other words, I heavily resent your view on my actions on this site and I have reported your comment as being unfriendly and unkind.

The urgency of your question isn’t a consideration in answering your question. I routinely remove irrelevant information or statements which indicate the urgency of a question.

By posting your question here, you just raised the priority by adding the Meta Effect to it.

@Lamper46: nice catch :-) but I assure you: this was not the intention!


Wouldn't that be a good idea to cover issues like mine?

No, because the purpose of Stack Overflow isn't to solve your current problem. Stack Overflow isn't a help desk. It's intended to be a repository of high quality questions and answers - and that doesn't have a priority.

I am very thankful for the speed on which you wrote a proposal to my question (it didn't work, but it might have and in case of problems in the future, I will certainly take it into account), but as far as your idea on priority, I disagree with that.

"Stack Overflow isn't a help desk." I'm afraid a lot of people did not get that memo. :(

@MisterMiyagi: Absolutely - but that doesn't mean we should change the feature set to turn it into a help desk.

@Dominique: If your question is good, it's just as important for the purpose of the site that it gets a good answer, regardless of whether it actually helps you personally.

did not get that memo (TPS reports)
